# Mocking a Lambda Argument with Mockito unable to find right ArgumentMatcher

Tags: java, lambda, mockito, jdbctemplate, method-reference

I've a code where I pass a lambda as a RowMapper to a framework class, which use this lambda to trigger a `org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(...)` method.
As this is Lambda and not a concrete class, I'm unable to find the correct `ArgumentMatchers` for mocking the behavior for my test.

Below is some oversimplified code for illustration

```
public abstract class FrameworkDao{
    protected <T> List<T> query(
                            MyStatement sql, 
                            RowMapper<T> handler) {
        //A lot of security and logging handling
        
        JdbcTemplate template = this.getTemplate(); 
        List<T> result = template.query(sql.getSql(), sql.getParameterArray(), handler);
        
        //A lot of security exception and logging handling
        
        return result;
    }
}

class MyDao extends FrameworkDao {
 
   public List<Model> getModels() {
        return query(new MyStatement(selectQuery,pram1,param2),
                     (rs, num) -> ModelConverter.convert(rs)
                  );
                                        
    }
 
 }
 
 class  ModelConverter {
          Model convert (ResultSet rs){....};
          Model convert (SomeOtherModel sm){....};
          Model convert (SomeOtherModel2 sm2){....};
 }
```

Now because `ModelConverter` is a one converter class for converting many things into Model class, it is not a dedicated `RowMapper` class to be used as a Mockito `ArgumentMatcher`.
I used method reference for one of the method in it as a RowMapper.

So my Junit Mocking is as follows

```
@Test
void testSomething(){
   List<Models> models = new ArrayList();
   //create test models & add with    models.add()

    doReturn(models)
                .when(jdbcTemplate)
                .query(any(String.class),
                        any(Object[].class),
                    (RowMapper<Object>) any(FunctionalInterface.class)); 

    ............
   }
```

Last line above test is problematic.

Because I'm passing a lambda here I'm unable to get the expected result out of Mocked `jdbcTemplate`.
At last line instead of `FunctionalInterface` I tried below also, but nothing works.

- `(RowMapper<Object>) any(Object.class)`
- `(RowMapper<Object>) any()`
- `any(RowMapper.class)`

Unfortunately I can neither change the `FrameworkDao` nor the `converter` class.

**So question is**
How to mock a Method with a lambda as a parameter

Comment: How about `Mockito.<RowMapper<Models>>any()`?

Comment: I have the same issue too